# Static struct global

Tags: c, linkage

I have defined two structs in different files with the same name using the keyword "static". This means they should only be visible within those files.

`void function()` in one of those files uses one of them.

If I declare `extern void function()` in the other, which struct will it use? The one where `function()` is defined, or the one where the `extern` function is used?

Comment: AFAIK, `static` doesn't do anything for struct definitions. It only relates to variable and function definitions. Best solution: use different names for your two structs.

Comment: The linkage will be external (i.e. not in the source file you call the extern function from) so according to the rules it will use the function in the other file; if that function simply references the structure (by not declaring the structure itself as extern) then it will be the structure in the file where function() is defined.

Comment: FWIW, declaring `extern void foo();` is the same as `void foo();` because the linkage for functions is `extern` by default.

Comment: The one which is defined in the same file as function().   If you want some other effect, you will have to modify function to take a pointer to the structure as an argument, and pass it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Anything declared "static" is not made visible to the linker outside of the .o file.  Your `extern function()` would only be able to access its local copy of the struct—it's going to be happily oblivious of other like-named structures in other files.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `extern` only applies to the linkage of the function.
It instructs to compiler that the function exists somewhere else, called external linkage.

The function is still compiled within the scope where the body is defined. Using the structure that is visible for the definition.